# I have one path(heart) , scaled to reduce size(width and height) with added transform value. I need difference width of added and scaled path

Tags: svg, path, width, transform

Below different transform values of same path

Path with first transform value.

```
<path id="cropMarkMask" class="bleedPath" d="M418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866C418.19489615365677,228.3214910972795,417.6135738169066,229.21559012608546,417.08911996962104,230.1633982838303C384.0200933459036,280.60890779953655,338.2093657215696,328.4195106367121,279.6569370966192,373.5983661558829C276.601835468155,375.8067591634284,273.5467338396908,378.0720206604385,270.4947915717524,380.38783192586175C254.17353509538623,391.86894807667755,239.22028172669843,397.3441198679169,225.63187210516324,396.81650666010563C225.42335431045936,396.81650666010563,225.26222692364274,396.81650666010563,225.1579680262908,396.81650666010563C225.1579680262908,396.81650666010563,224.8420319737092,396.81650666010563,224.8420319737092,396.81650666010563C224.63351417900532,396.81650666010563,224.4723867921887,396.81650666010563,224.36812789483676,396.81650666010563C210.78287763382738,397.3441198679169,195.82962426513959,391.86894807667755,179.5052084282476,380.38783192586175C176.45326616030923,378.0720206604385,173.39816453184503,375.8067591634284,170.34306290338083,373.5983661558829C111.79063427843042,328.4195106367121,65.97990665409648,280.60890779953655,32.91088003037898,230.1633982838303C32.383266822567684,229.21559012608546,31.805103846343336,228.3214910972795,31.173231741180103,227.4779418368866C7.689704952788771,188.09335352206264,-2.527666987700611,149.91564092810046,0.5274346407635936,112.95112277605168C3.4782773718758646,76.09086352135482,19.221370872017665,47.02474668384638,47.75987450171482,25.752772263526335C93.25466607346718,-8.156644260058247,144.3825974627497,-8.57999857051761,201.14682803008822,24.48902805319989C209.1494882419805,29.22806884192409,216.88992153023005,31.439621209995384,224.36812789483682,31.123685157413775C224.57980505006645,31.123685157413775,224.78832284477033,31.123685157413775,225.00000000000003,31.123685157413775C225.2085177947039,31.123685157413775,225.42019494993357,31.123685157413775,225.63187210516327,31.123685157413775C233.1100784697701,31.335362312643458,240.85051175801962,29.123809944572166,248.85317196991187,24.48902805319989C305.61740253725037,-8.579998570517605,356.7453339265329,-8.156644260058242,402.2401254982853,25.752772263526335C430.78178848850814,47.02474668384638,446.52488198865,76.09402288188062,449.4725653592364,112.95112277605168C452.5276669877007,149.91564092810046,442.31029504721124,188.09335352206264,418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866C418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866,418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866,418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866" width="357.21000000000004" height="315.02055178728943" aWidth="0" aHeight="0" x="71.39499999999998" y="92.48972410635528" aX="0" aY="0" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" style="pointer-events: none; display: block;" display="none" transform="translate(107.11599999999999,128.2063399552543) scale(0.63504,0.6138000000000001)"></path>
```

Path with second transform value.

```
<path id="safeMarkMask" class="bleedPath" d="M418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866C418.19489615365677,228.3214910972795,417.6135738169066,229.21559012608546,417.08911996962104,230.1633982838303C384.0200933459036,280.60890779953655,338.2093657215696,328.4195106367121,279.6569370966192,373.5983661558829C276.601835468155,375.8067591634284,273.5467338396908,378.0720206604385,270.4947915717524,380.38783192586175C254.17353509538623,391.86894807667755,239.22028172669843,397.3441198679169,225.63187210516324,396.81650666010563C225.42335431045936,396.81650666010563,225.26222692364274,396.81650666010563,225.1579680262908,396.81650666010563C225.1579680262908,396.81650666010563,224.8420319737092,396.81650666010563,224.8420319737092,396.81650666010563C224.63351417900532,396.81650666010563,224.4723867921887,396.81650666010563,224.36812789483676,396.81650666010563C210.78287763382738,397.3441198679169,195.82962426513959,391.86894807667755,179.5052084282476,380.38783192586175C176.45326616030923,378.0720206604385,173.39816453184503,375.8067591634284,170.34306290338083,373.5983661558829C111.79063427843042,328.4195106367121,65.97990665409648,280.60890779953655,32.91088003037898,230.1633982838303C32.383266822567684,229.21559012608546,31.805103846343336,228.3214910972795,31.173231741180103,227.4779418368866C7.689704952788771,188.09335352206264,-2.527666987700611,149.91564092810046,0.5274346407635936,112.95112277605168C3.4782773718758646,76.09086352135482,19.221370872017665,47.02474668384638,47.75987450171482,25.752772263526335C93.25466607346718,-8.156644260058247,144.3825974627497,-8.57999857051761,201.14682803008822,24.48902805319989C209.1494882419805,29.22806884192409,216.88992153023005,31.439621209995384,224.36812789483682,31.123685157413775C224.57980505006645,31.123685157413775,224.78832284477033,31.123685157413775,225.00000000000003,31.123685157413775C225.2085177947039,31.123685157413775,225.42019494993357,31.123685157413775,225.63187210516327,31.123685157413775C233.1100784697701,31.335362312643458,240.85051175801962,29.123809944572166,248.85317196991187,24.48902805319989C305.61740253725037,-8.579998570517605,356.7453339265329,-8.156644260058242,402.2401254982853,25.752772263526335C430.78178848850814,47.02474668384638,446.52488198865,76.09402288188062,449.4725653592364,112.95112277605168C452.5276669877007,149.91564092810046,442.31029504721124,188.09335352206264,418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866C418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866,418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866,418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866" width="357.21000000000004" height="315.02055178728943" aWidth="0" aHeight="0" x="71.39499999999998" y="92.48972410635528" aX="0" aY="0" fill="none" stroke="#2B8F49" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="5,5" style="pointer-events: none; display: block;" display="none" transform="translate(142.837,163.92295580415333) scale(0.47628000000000004,0.43380000000000013)"></path>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please try to rephrase what you are asking?

Comment: I have rephrase the question you can try to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly answering your question but I think you'll find it useful. I draw 2 rectangles, one for each heart: the transformed bounding box. The code is giving you (please open the console) the size and the position of those boxes so that you can calculate the difference you need:

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
const svg = document.querySelector("svg")

let heart_bbox = heart.getBBox();
// untransformed heart
let W0 = heart_bbox.width;
let H0 = heart_bbox.height;
let x0 = heart_bbox.x;
let y0 = heart_bbox.y;
// red heart

let bbox1 = {
width: W0 * 0.635,
height: H0 * 0.614,
x : x0 + 107.116,
y : y0 + 128.206
}

console.log("red heart",bbox1);

// green heart

let bbox2 = {
width: W0 * 0.476,
height: H0 * 0.434,
x : x0 + 142.837,
y : y0 + 163.923
}

console.log("green heart",bbox2);

drawRect(bbox1, svg)
drawRect(bbox2, svg)



function drawRect(o, parent) {

  let rect = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'rect');
  for (let name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      rect.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(rect);
  return rect;
}
```

```css
rect{stroke:#d9d9d9; fill:none;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "-10 -10 500 500">
  <defs>
    <path id="heart" d="M418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866C418.19489615365677,228.3214910972795,417.6135738169066,229.21559012608546,417.08911996962104,230.1633982838303C384.0200933459036,280.60890779953655,338.2093657215696,328.4195106367121,279.6569370966192,373.5983661558829C276.601835468155,375.8067591634284,273.5467338396908,378.0720206604385,270.4947915717524,380.38783192586175C254.17353509538623,391.86894807667755,239.22028172669843,397.3441198679169,225.63187210516324,396.81650666010563C225.42335431045936,396.81650666010563,225.26222692364274,396.81650666010563,225.1579680262908,396.81650666010563C225.1579680262908,396.81650666010563,224.8420319737092,396.81650666010563,224.8420319737092,396.81650666010563C224.63351417900532,396.81650666010563,224.4723867921887,396.81650666010563,224.36812789483676,396.81650666010563C210.78287763382738,397.3441198679169,195.82962426513959,391.86894807667755,179.5052084282476,380.38783192586175C176.45326616030923,378.0720206604385,173.39816453184503,375.8067591634284,170.34306290338083,373.5983661558829C111.79063427843042,328.4195106367121,65.97990665409648,280.60890779953655,32.91088003037898,230.1633982838303C32.383266822567684,229.21559012608546,31.805103846343336,228.3214910972795,31.173231741180103,227.4779418368866C7.689704952788771,188.09335352206264,-2.527666987700611,149.91564092810046,0.5274346407635936,112.95112277605168C3.4782773718758646,76.09086352135482,19.221370872017665,47.02474668384638,47.75987450171482,25.752772263526335C93.25466607346718,-8.156644260058247,144.3825974627497,-8.57999857051761,201.14682803008822,24.48902805319989C209.1494882419805,29.22806884192409,216.88992153023005,31.439621209995384,224.36812789483682,31.123685157413775C224.57980505006645,31.123685157413775,224.78832284477033,31.123685157413775,225.00000000000003,31.123685157413775C225.2085177947039,31.123685157413775,225.42019494993357,31.123685157413775,225.63187210516327,31.123685157413775C233.1100784697701,31.335362312643458,240.85051175801962,29.123809944572166,248.85317196991187,24.48902805319989C305.61740253725037,-8.579998570517605,356.7453339265329,-8.156644260058242,402.2401254982853,25.752772263526335C430.78178848850814,47.02474668384638,446.52488198865,76.09402288188062,449.4725653592364,112.95112277605168C452.5276669877007,149.91564092810046,442.31029504721124,188.09335352206264,418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866C418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866,418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866,418.8267682588199,227.4779418368866" />
    
  </defs>  
  
  <use xlink:href ="#heart" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" transform="translate(107.11599999999999,128.2063399552543) scale(0.63504,0.6138000000000001)"></use>
  
  
  <use xlink:href ="#heart" fill="none" stroke="#2B8F49" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-dasharray="5,5" transform="translate(142.837,163.92295580415333) scale(0.47628000000000004,0.43380000000000013)"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: I will try with this.